# Android studio not working as it should work

Tags: android-studio

Yesterday I configured my Android Studio according to the tutorial I saw. The next day, I opened Android studio and the *logcat*, and many of the other things on toolbar were not showing up and grayed out.

Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Android studio image]

Comment: go to File>Invalidate>invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Still the run, debug and other options grayed  out

Comment: paste you snapshot

Comment: @Harsh Sason It might happen if the project sync failed. Try to do a gradle sync first.

Comment: See the image i posted,

Comment: Look at the bottom of the window. Are there any messages in the status bar?

Comment: @Sanjeet gradle sync didnt work

Comment: How did you open your project?

Answer (score 1):

Just click the dropdown button on left side of RUN button and then Edit Configurations...

then click on Android Application on the left and click the + button. Choose "Android App" from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module and select "app". Then click apply and ok.

[image]

If you have more errors after that, try to reopen project, it could be caused due to directory error, make sure you correctly target project when browsing and opening the target directory which contains the files.

```
...\AndroidStudioProjects\YourAppName\{project files}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if there is already a configuration named "app", the OP can just use that.

Comment: yes, but i think he doesn't have it configured, or maybe the error is due to directory structure.

Comment: still this detail is good to note in case the default configuration exists and somehow is not selected. This is for both the OP and any future visitors who land on this question

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an run configuration. To do so, click the dropdown box to the left of the Run button. If you already have a run configuration, just select it. If not, click on Edit Confirgurations.... Then click on the + button at the top left and select Android App. Enter a descriptive name and select the `app` module. Finally, click OK. The Run button should now become enabled.